# Bootstrap input tags apply required validation

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrapvalidator

I am using bootstrap tags input https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/ and implemented as well successfully. I just want to made it ***required field*** so that each user submit form with the technology tags.

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
 <label class="">Primary Skills (Note: Add comma separated) <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
 <input class="form-control" type="text" id="primaryskill" name="seeker_primary_skills" required>
 <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right">This is a required</b>
</div>
```

Here is the screenshot for this.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

check return on form submit

```
<form onsubmit="return checktag()">
```

Javascript/Jquery Code

```
function checktag(){
   if($("#primaryskill").val() == ''){
      alert("Tags Required"); //Here you can simple alert or change input css with 
      border red with msg with the help of jquery
      return false;
   }else{
        return true; 
   }
}
```

Comment: BOOTSTRAP VALIDATOR ALREADY APPLIED SO NOT USE THIS TYPE OF EVENT.